# How to restore a SQL Server database from a Schema Objects folder?

Tags: sql-server, schema, database-restore

I received a Schema Objects folder like this:

```
Schema Objects 
|-- Tables 
  |-- Constraints
  |-- Indexes
  |-- Keys
  |-- Statistics
  |-- Triggers
  |-- ..and all the SQL scripts to create the tables
```

How do I restore this database to SQL Server, other than running script by script?

Comment: IF you have visual studio pro or higher you should be able to add the files to a database project and then use VS deploy database option to create the schema in an empty database in a couple of mouse clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you have visual studio pro or higher you should be able to add the files to a database project and then use VS deploy database option to create the schema in an empty database in a couple of mouse clicks